# Selected Value Combo Box not binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Ok so I have spent hours now trying to figure this out and I cant. 
I have the below combo box which is binding correctly to my collection of data.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbx" Width="250" Height="25"
   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsComboBox,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Answers}"
   SelectedValuePath="AnswerId"
   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="Answer"/>
```

The Selected Item however is not populating top my Selected Answer property. I put a textbox on the form and bound it to SelectedAnswer.Answer and that is binding to the answer correctly. 
For some reason though my combo box will not bind the selected answer

- I have read something about the layout of the combo box property and tried changing that, also stepped through the getter and setter of the property to ensure it is not clearing down (which is not as it will bind to the text box)

Please help with this.

SurveyAnswer:

```
public class SurveyAnswer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Guid answerId;
    public Guid AnswerId
    {
        get { return answerId; }
        set { 
            answerId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AnswerId");
        }
    }

    private string answer;
    public string Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set { 
            answer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Answer");
        }
    }

    public Guid SurveyLineID { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set { 
            isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }


    #region NotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion        

}
```

Comment: Can you post how is the `Answers` collection and `SelectedAnswer` property populated and also the implementation of the `SelectedAnswer` property?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change SelectedItem to SelectedValue. Sometimes that order of parameters matters as well.

```
 <ComboBox Name="cbx" Width="250" Height="25"                                                          
   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsComboBox,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Answers}"         
   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="Answer" SelectedValuePath="AnswerId"/>
```

This is helpful:
http://johnpapa.net/binding-to-silverlight-combobox-and-using-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath-and-displaymemberpath

Comment: Tried changing my Combo Box to that exactly and it is still not binding the selected value

Comment: If you run in debug mode, is there any binding errors in the output window? Better yet, if you're running in SL5, you can put a breakpoint in and debug it. Can you post what your Answer object looks like?

Comment: Posted SelectedAnswer object - Checked in Output window and there are no binding issues. If it was an issue with the Answers object would'nt it fail to bind on the text box

Comment: You're right about the binding in the textbox. The GUID shouldn't matter, but maybe the combobox doesn't know how to handle them for selection. What if you changed it to a string for a quick test?